Test whether my new method's type I error rate correctly matches chosen alpha
I am testing two different methods for hypothesis testing, bootstrapped likelihood ratio tests, and likelihood ratio tests assuming an asymptotic distribution. I would like to see if the number of rejections at the alpha=5% level is different from 0.05.
Based on this answer to an earlier question (is it correct by the way?), I want to do a binomial test to compare the empirical rejection rate and see whether it is different from 0.05.
However, an alternative solution I am considering is to do a comparative error rate test as described here (and see also here).  It does seem the results of the two tests do not fully agree with each other, so I think they are different.
You can compare the two methods as follows.  Say my new method has a rejection rate of 5.8% across 5000 samples (so I reject 290).  I can do a binomial test in R as follows
stats::binom.test(x=290,n=5000,p=0.05,conf.level=0.95)

    Exact binomial test

data:  290 and 5000
number of successes = 290, number of trials = 5000, p-value = 0.01133
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.05
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05168068 0.06484127
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                 0.058 

And thus I can reject the idea that my test has the proper rejection rate.
For the second method, we can use this online calculator suggested in the other post, by saying Sample Size 1 = 5000, Percentage Response 1 = 5.8, Sample Size 2 =5000, Percentage Response 2 = 5.  And we get the following results: Comparative Error :0.89, Difference :0.8, Significance :No.
My guess is that the binomial test correctly tells me what I really care about, whether or not the rejection rate of my new method is correct or not in the sense of whether it matches my alpha value.  However, I'm comparing a few different methods, and perhaps the "comparative error" measurement could be useful in some way for comparing methods?

The linked answer is correct (+1). (Answers from that user are generally of very high quality.)

I recommend making the question more focused. Right now it asks about various methods, some of which may be appropriate here, some not (you did not 'observe' Response 2), you want to know how to determine a type I error rate, but maybe also a sign error rate, and in what scenario what method is acceptable for peer-review is not really a statistics question.

Fish, is your question partly about the fact that. 1. Typically, assumptions are made when proposing a test (distributional assumptions, homoskedasticity, large dataset for asymptotic argument) 2. These assumptions might not hold in practice. 3. Thus, the practical rate might not match the nominal rate. Is that the issue underlying your question?

yes. I know for a fact that one of the existing literature methods I am trying to improve on has an elevated type I error rate of 10% at the 5% alpha level on simulated data (in other words 10% of null data has a p-value below 0.05 with the current hypothesis test method).  I actually have no idea why this is the case, so I am developing a few different bootstrapping approaches and I would like to compare them to each other, to the existing test, and to the expectations of a proper hypothesis test.

I suppose one dream goal could be that if different tests give different error rates, I could use the differences in the assumptions between the tests to try and figure out why the existing test is being tricked into having such an elevated type I error rate.

Right, so you are trying to do the same thing as caron, right? Show that, in some domain of application, the bootstrap test is better than some other test because the other test fails to have proper error rate, due to its assumptions, being unsatisfied. Understanding why is probably also possible but might require sophisticated analysis of the methods and a lot of understanding of stats.

(and bootstrap is typically going to be much better in terms of having proper rate because it assumes very little),

yes, exactly.  Although currently I do not feel comfortable simply asserting that observed rejection rates outside of [.025,0.75] mean the test has failed.  Instead I am planning to do a binomial test on each observed rejection rate to see if it is different than 0.05.  This would be the only difference with Caron

ah, I see. Then that's a (common) mistake. In Caron, all of the differences are statistically significant: they have 5000 repetitions so the error bars vanish. We don't really care about the nominal rate being statistically different from 0.05. We care about the rate being meaningfully different from 0.05. A statistically significant rate of 0.49999 is not meaningfully different. Caron defines meanginful to be outside of 0.025, 0.075 and that is reasonable.

Empirical validation of null-rejection methods
tldr:

in null-rejection testing, the empirical rate is typically different than the nominal rate (due to approximations), but it only matters if it is meaningfully different.
if you think the rate is $5%$ but it's actually $4.9%$, that difference doesn't matter. If it's $10%$, that's very different.
running experiments on artificial data are a good way to check how the empirical rate behaves.

1. The setup
Let's consider the following situation. We are doing some science , and, in our experiment, we want to compare two classes. We have:

a null hypothesis $H_0$: the two classes are identical
the alternative $H_1$: the two classes are different

Note, even in the simplest case $H_1$ is an ensemble! In complex examples, $H_0$ is also an ensemble.


a number of possibles tests. These are methods which label an input dataset as having a significant difference $S_1$ or unsignificant difference $S_0$

For example, we might want to see whether two groups of values have the same distribution (null hypothesis) or not. To do so, we might test whether they have the same empirical mean or empirical median or empirical variance, etc.
We want to validate the general worth of these various tests for a particular problem.
2. The measures
In a frequentist framework, we have two canonical measures associated to this problem.

the false positive rate (FPR): for a given null model (ie, a given element of $H_0$), the rate at which the algorithm produces a $S_1$ result.
the false negative rate (FNR): for a given non-null model (ie, a given element of $H_1$), the rate at which the algorithm produces a $S_0$ result.

Typically, the FPR is exactly the same throughout $H_0$, but that is not necessary. Technically, the usual guarantee is that the false positive rate is, at most, some $\alpha$ close to 0 (typically 0.05 or 0.01 or 0.001). $\alpha$ is sometimes called the level of the test.
In contrast, typically, the FNR varies as we vary the non-null model: it is a function of the specific non-null model. This is understandable: some cases are more easy to discriminate from a null while some are more ambiguous. In our example, if we are using the empirical mean, it is easier to reject the null if the difference of the true means is 100 instead of 1 (keeping the variances constant). This function of non-null model to FNR is called the power function of the test.
The FPR and FNR are linked. Typically, the rate of classification is continuous as we vary the model. For models that are thus almost-null (there is an effect but almost imperceptible, ie: the two means are almost identical), the FNR is $1 - \alpha$. If we go further from the null, then the FNR is going to go down in some method-specific way.
3. Empirical validation
Critically, when we design a test to have a given FPR $\alpha$, there are typically assumptions being made about the ensemble $H_0$, and the ensemble $H_1$. For example, we might make assumptions about the data distribution, dependence structure, etc. We might also make assumptions about the data being large-enough (and the distributions being well-behaved) to justify asymptotic approximations of key intermediate quantities. These assumptions might not be valid for the kind of experiments we are performing in a specific domain.
We thus might want to check that, in a number of experiments with controlled generative model (ie: data which we generate ourselves from a known model) the theoretical properties of the method (derived from the analysis) match the empirical properties (which we can observe in the epxeriments). This is the approach of Caron, 2017
For example, we can choose a specific model in $H_0$, generate some large number $m$ of datasets from that model, and measure the empirical rate of $S_1$.
We can then compare that empirical rate to the theoretical rate.
Critically, we are not interested in whether the difference is statistically significant. We should take $m$ large enough so that the error bars on the empirical rate are much smaller than the theoretical rate $\alpha$. As a consequence, we can consider that the empirical rate is constant. In the results from the Caron paper, almost all their empirical rates are statistically different from the nominal rate.
What we should care about is whether the difference is meaningful. Indeed, the FPR being $4.99%$ is not far enough from $5%$ to care. Caron gives the following rule: he highlights all cases where the theoretical rate is $5%$ but the empirical rate is lower than $2.5%$ or higher than $7.5%$. The details of that boundary are subjective, but that sounds about right to me.
If we want to be absolutely thorough, we should also investigate the FNR of the methods in $H_1$. However, due to the link of the FRP to the $1-FNR$ for almost-null models, this is not necessarily needed.
Note, like all experiments, the goal should be to extract meaning and intuition from the results. This should require some careful thinking about how to explore the ensemble $H_0$ and $H_1$ and summarize the results.
Note that, typically, we should expect the bootstrap tests to be succesful in such experiments because they are designed to minimize assumptions about the data.

This is not an answer about statistical methods, but only to point out that it is common practice in the literature to not actually test whether a rejection rate is significantly different than the alpha value, but instead simply eye ball it.
For example Caron 2019 simply says that rejection rates outside of [0.025, 0.075] will be considered bad.
Similarly, Nestler Salditt 2024, PETRINOVICH and HARDYCK 1969, and Cooper et. al. 2016 all seem to eye ball it, though I am not 100% sure.
I've only found one paper so far that assessed the rejection rates as being significantly different than the alpha value, but I've lost the link to it.

Wait. Isn't Caron 2019 exactly computing a bunch of actual error rates? I really don't understand what you mean when you say: "it is common practice in the literature to eyeball whether a rejection rate is significantly different than the alpha"

(part 1 of 2) yes. they compute the actual error rates but because they use simulated data it is not obvious if the rate differs from 0.05 because of randomness or because the tests are different.  On page 4 they write "Within tables, light blue
colored cells point out very low type I error rate defined as below the .025 threshold. Light
red colored cells point out very high type I error rate, above de .075 threshold." ...

(part 2 of 2) Similarly, if one test is .024 and another  is .023 are these similarly underpowered or maybe one of them is significantly more underpowered than the other.  Granted, I do not know if this makes sense as a question to ask or if it's something that can be addressed with the simulation data in the paper, this is part of my confusion

Just making sure we are on the same page, power is about correctly rejecting the null when it is invalid, as a function of the effect size. So far, we have focused on discussing whether the error rate at the null matches the nominal rate.

For their table, they have 5000 simulations, so the resulting rate can be considered constant at the precision they are reporting it. Any reasonable CI is going to vanish into the decimals.

So their analysis makes complete sense to me. They create a bunch of toy situations (which have limitations, of course; I haven't looked into the details enough to know whether they did a good job there) and investigate how the methods behave and try to build some intuition on that basis. Their "eyeball" report is, in my opinion, trying to focus on the important regions, where the deviation between nominal and real rate is "unacceptable". That's going to be subjective, they set the bar at 50% relative error, which sounds about right. I agree with their approach

oh that's interesting (about being able to consider the rejection rate as practically constant).  And what you say about the eyeballing being reasonable makes sense to me.  Also, I don't understand power well enough to be on any page :(  But I suppose for now I am just trying to get any method with a the correct type I error rate.  If I found multiple then I suppose selecting the most powerful would be good, but yeah, I'm not at that stage.  I know one way to increase power is to increase the alpha level from say 0.01 to 0.05, that's the only reason I brought it up.

"I know one way to increase power is to increase the alpha level from say 0.01 to 0.05, that's the only reason I brought it up". Yes, correct. I had forgotten about that. The website is complaining on my end that we are taking too much space in the comments. I'll do a detailed write-up in an answer. do you mind if I also edit your question for clarity? (you'll be able to review the changes, I think?)

yes. I would appreciate it if you improved my question.  I don't know what additional detail you were thinking of adding, but I think everything you've said so far in the comments is plenty satisfactory, so I don't think you need to do the work of retyping everything into a formal answer.  I like your idea from the other comment thread about meaningful versus significant differences in error rates.  I never thought it about it from that perspective before.  The only fear I have about this is ...

what if the assumption violations that cause the incorrect error rate means there is an underlying meaningful difference in the results even if the error rates themselves are not meaningfully different.  But even if that were true, I suppose it's not something that can really be addressed by studying if the error rates are significantly different anyways as you discussed in the 6th comment of the other thread.
